# Tool for smoothing values based on neighboor analysis in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, reclassify

I have a raster with areas of different values. Lets say area 1 has values that range from 1 to 10 while area 2 has values that range from 30 to 40. Now I also have one value of 35 in area 1.

Is there a tool that can detect those irregular values and revalue them all based on a neighboor analysis?

Answer (score 1):

I tested several raster filters, so far none of them corrected irregular values without affecting adjacent cell values (I thought it was also one of your agenda).

Among them two filters produced relatively good result (adjusted the irregular cell value 35; while changes in neighbor cells remained relatively minor).

**Sample**

Left: Area 1 (1~10) with anomaly (35), Right: Area 2 (30~40)

[image]

**Multi direction Lee Filter**   Not too bad, but distorted broad area.

[image]

**Rank Filter (50%)**  Probably the best one as far as I saw. Please ignore edge area.

[image]

Some did not work e.g., Mesh denoise, DTM filter.

Other filters I have not tried: FFT, Gaussian, etc...